# Sequence of dictionaries in python

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to create a sequence of similar dictionaries to further store them in a tuple. I tried two approaches, using and not using a for loop

Without for loop

```
dic0 = {'modo': lambda x: x[0]}
dic1 = {'modo': lambda x: x[1]}
lst = []
lst.append(dic0)
lst.append(dic1)
tup = tuple(lst)
dic0 = tup[0]
dic1 = tup[1]
f0 = dic0['modo']
f1 = dic1['modo']
x = np.array([0,1])
print (f0(x) , f1(x))  # 0 , 1
```

With a for loop

```
lst = []
for j in range(0,2):
    dic = {}
    dic = {'modo': lambda x: x[j]}
    lst.insert(j,dic)
tup = tuple(lst)
dic0 = tup[0]
dic1 = tup[1]
f0 = dic0['modo']
f1 = dic1['modo']
x = np.array([0,1])
print (f0(x) , f1(x))   # 1 , 1
```

I really don't understand why I am getting different results. It seems that the last dictionary I insert overwrite the previous ones, but I don't know why (the append method does not work neither).

Any help would be really welcomed

Comment: in `lambda x: x[j]}`, `j` is evaluated when the lambda is executed, so its value is always 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to how scoping works in this case. Try putting `j = 0` above the final print statement and you'll see what happens.

Also, you might try

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [{'modo': itemgetter(j)} for j in range(2)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your proposed solutions works fine

Answer (score 0):

You have accidentally created what is know as a [*closure.*](http://ynniv.com/blog/2007/08/closures-in-python.html) The lambda functions in your second (loop-based) example include a reference to a variable `j`. That variable is actually the loop variable used to iterate your loop. So the `lambda` call actually produces code with a reference to "some variable named 'j' that I didn't define, but it's around here somewhere."

This is called "closing over" or "enclosing" the variable `j`, because even when the loop is finished, there will be this lambda function you wrote that references the variable `j`. And so it will never get garbage-collected until you release the references to the lambda function(s).

You get the same value (1, 1) printed because `j` stops iterating over the `range(0,2)` with j=1, and nothing changes that. So when your lambda functions ask for x[j], they're asking for the *present value* of `j`, then getting the *present value* of `x[j]`. In both functions, the present value of j is 1.

You could work around this by creating a `make_lambda` function that takes an index number as a parameter. Or you could do what @DavisYoshida suggested, and use someone else's code to create the appropriate closure for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your have made this problem very clear to me with your explanation